# Making HTML div more awesome way

Tags: html, css, background

Is there any way to make the background as following image.

[image]

Should I use to three div classes to create this kind of background. I have no clear idea. I tried to find a way from google. But I couldn't. Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: No use an svg or an image as background!

Comment: create a image(style it in photoshop...and ect) and use `background-image`  :)

Comment: Thank you all. I'll create an image.

Comment: Please make an effort to properly title your questions - “Making HTML div more awesome way” is a very poor choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single image as the background or you can use say two images as a background - top and then bottom. the second way maybe better for a responsive layout but i dont know enough details to be able to say either way.

Using two background images would look something like this:

```
.yourclass {
    background-image:url(yourimage.png), url(yourotherimage.png);
    background-position:top left, bottom right;
}
```